# Pub failed to delete entry because it was in use by another process

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to configure my Flutter project to work on the web. I switched to the master channel using `flutter channel master` after doing this I tried to run `flutter upgrade`. I am now getting an infinite loop saying:

```
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Pub failed to delete entry because it was in use by another process.
This may be caused by a virus scanner or having a file
in the directory open in another application.
Error (1): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)

Waiting for 0 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ...
Running pub upgrade...
Pub failed to delete entry because it was in use by another process.
This may be caused by a virus scanner or having a file
in the directory open in another application.
Error (1): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (8 tries left)

Waiting for 2 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ...
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? Y
```

I have tried multiple things such as running `flutter clean`, trying to change back to the stable channel, deleting the cache folder in the flutter/bin directory, turning off my windows defender, nothing seems to work. Now when I try to run `flutter doctor`, or any other flutter command, I get the same infinite loop with the same message. I have also tried manually downloading and replacing my flutter sdk installation with a new installation, this did not work either. Is my only option at this point to delete flutter completely and reinstall from scratch?

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this.

Comment: Try restarting the computer, maybe some process is still accessing some Flutter files.

Comment: I have tried this twice already. I still get the same issue. Thank you for the suggestion, however.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. There are also some solutions in [this thread](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1798) if it helps.

Comment: No worries thank you so much.

Comment: I have the same problem here!

Comment: in my case the problem was caused when I manutally added the flame package to my pubspec.yaml file.  I removed the package and instead ran the command: flutter pub add flame

Answer (score 34):

I ran my compiler as an administrator, and it worked for me.
Open your Android Studio or Visual Studio as an admin.

Answer (score 19):

I was running into this issue and discovered that the problem was a new dependency that I added. In my case it was `assets_audio_player: ^3.0.3+1`, but of course it could be any dependency. Deleting it immediately fixed my problem.

Comment: There is some issue with this package specifically. Hope so developers will fix it soon.

Comment: so there is no other way to fixing it without me having to delete that package?

Comment: There's most likely some issue with the package itself you could go in and fix but I think it'd be quicker and more effective to find a different similar package that's well maintained.

Comment: For those of you having this problem try to use the assets_audio_player in the same project as done by the repo (florent37) then use the package in the example folder in the pubspec.yaml as followed:    `assets_audio_player:
   path: ../ ` in `dev_dependencies:`. This worked for me I guess?

Answer (score 11):

Faced this problem and had to run "start ms-settings:developers" at terminal. It solved the issue.

Comment: That was exactly was I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Comment: Perfect, Buddy.

Answer (score 10):

On windows: Run vscode, or the terminal you are using, as admin to resolve the problem.
For Linux: I think some kind of sudo approach could do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

run
flutter upgrade
in an external admin cmd console

Answer (score 1):

Running VS Code or Android Studio as Administrator, will probably solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[use powershell (admin) to fix this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOMaw.jpg) I got same problem and fix this using Windows PowerShell (Admin). Just type flutter

Answer (score 0):

switch your channel to stable or master using command "flutter channel stable"

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. I recommend instead of C:/src/flutter, you put the flutter folder inside C:/ direct. Would be like this:

C:/flutter

If that doesn't solve it, try pausing your anti-virus just for us to test. It could be that it is blocking the permissions on local disk C folder. It's not very common, but it can happen sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me close all android studio tabs, after open a cmd as admin, go to your folder (if the command requires it) and execute the command again

Answer (score -2):

The only solution is to run android studio as administrator.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in other answers. And also this is wrong.