# Flutter Blue error try run Flutter_Blue_exemple

Tags: flutter

Hello I'm new work with flutter but a try run a Flutter blue example but I have a error in import
I add flutter_blue: ^0.8.0 in pubspec.yaml and run flutter pub get but whem I import import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart'; The IDE give error I go show in picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnAtc.png)

I try create new project restart de IDE and run flutter pub get and flutter pub upgrade

Comment: For me, sometimes VS Code continues showing this error even after running `flutter pub get`. When this happens, I simply went ahead with running the app, and if it runs, you should be ok.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **DO NOT** attach images of errors. They cannot be copy/pasted, indexed by search engines, and can be blocked by filters. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add your error as formatted text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035), along with [this website](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `flutter pub get` command in your console?

If u add your pubspec.yaml file it will be helpful too.

Comment: When I run flutter pub get VS don't show anyone erro but when I run in Android Studio or in console give me this `Pub failed to delete entry because it was in use by another process.
This may be caused by a virus scanner or having a file
in the directory open in another application.
pub get failed
command: "C:\Users\User\Documents\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart __deprecated_pub --directory . get --example"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "C:\Users\User\Documents\flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
  "PUB_CACHE": "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache",
}
exit code: 1`

Comment: @tiagogomes Try some of these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67578189/pub-failed-to-delete-entry-because-it-was-in-use-by-another-process

Comment: You're welcome, you can check my answer as correct if it resolved your problem.