# Flutter blue pub discrepancy

Tags: flutter

PS C:\Users\hp\Desktop\See\myapp> flutter pub add flutter_blue

Resolving dependencies...

Pub failed to delete entry because it was in use by another process.

This may be caused by a virus scanner or having a file

in the directory open in another application.

PS C:\Users\hp\Desktop\See\myapp>

This is the error I get. It says that there was discrepancy when setting up the package flutter blue. I turned if windows security when installing the package and some other things

But it didn't work. What can I do ?

I Uninstalled the flutter blue package and reinstalled it but this time by turning windows windows firewall.

I scrapped several projects and created new ones

I rebooted the whole system

And also performed a combination of these

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pub failed to delete entry because it was in use by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67578189/pub-failed-to-delete-entry-because-it-was-in-use-by-another-process)